# How can I stop automatic download of my PDF in Firefox?

Tags: pdf, firefox, iframe, download, disable

I have some code on my site that works like this:

1. Code for invisible iframes at bottom of page containing URLs to PDFs
2. HTML button for each PDF which takes users directly to the print preview (without opening the PDF viewer)

This is in place to offer an alternative printing option, and also to make printing the documents even faster for our users.

**However, my PROBLEM is...**

We have since realised that there is a setting in Firefox that users can check which sets the default response to PDFs detected on a page to Download/Save As.

We can't have downloadable PDFs on the site as it is protected content.

**Is there a way of either:**

a) Disabling the automatic download of PDFs on our site?

or

b) Disabling the iframe altogether in Firefox only? (this particular print function only works for Chrome and Edge anyway)

Any help would be great!

Comment: Just to add, our site is a WordPress site, using the Divi theme. Just in case there are any ways that I have missed for disabling sections based on the browser being used.

Comment: Opinion: having something on the web that works on a specific browser only is bad, and usually indicates some *code smell*. Moreover blocking downloading PDFs on specific browser doesn't really solve your problem: one could simply use a "PDF printer" to work around such restriction.

Comment: Hi Dexter, thanks for your response. As the alternative printing function described above only works with Chrome (the buttons even say "Print with Chrome") there is no need for the function of the iframe/buttons to be present at all for Firefox (or other browsers for that matter). Users of these other browsers would not be able to use this print function if the iframe was there or not. However, the fact that the PDFs can automatically download if a particular setting is selected in Firefox does cause an issue.

Comment: I know there is the same setting in other browsers too (choose to download pdfs when detected rather than open them) - Is there any way of blocking this for iframe content?